# Building a kernel

Tags: linux, fedora, kernel, compiling, make

I'm trying to build a custom kernel and I try to build it using `make` command but I get a `No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop.` error. Then I searched for the makefile in the folders SOURCES and SPECS (was not needed) but didn't get it.  I have built the same kernel using `rpmbuild` so I think there's no problem with source rpm. I'm trying to build using chroot.

Questions:

1. Which folder contains the makefile by default?
2. What are the steps to build the kernel using `make`?

Answer (score 0):

By default, the makefile for the kernel is often located in `/usr/src/linux/`. However, if you're using `chroot` to build your kernel, there is no way to know where you installed that file. Try building a kernel without `chroot` first to get a better understanding of the process.

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured it first?

Usually in the directory where the kernel is you

`make menuconfig`

once you've done that you compile it

`make`

You will need to grab the new kernel from where Dmitry stated and place it in /boot and modify your GRUB so that it points to the new kernel in the next boot, or even better, modify your GRUB so that a new menu option is presented where you can choose between old kernels and the new one.

Comment: Of course he didn't configure it yet, `make menuconfig` requires a valid makefile to be present. It's also not strictly necessary, since kernel source packages usually include a default `.config` file which works well enough.

Comment: i installed source rpm and firmware rpm for a processor family i586. Now i got rpmbuild dir. I searched for linux-3.8.0 and untared it in the SOURCES dir inside the rpmbuild dir. then i used make menuconfig i got a text based prompt in which there were so many options. I don't know how to configure it.

Comment: Questions:    1. why do we need to configure it?        2. How to configure it ?

Comment: Because you are bulding a custom kernel, arent you? you are suppossed to select some options and discard others. If you don't know how to configure it you would probably don't need to create a custom kernel. As for the second question, how to configure the kernel for your needs is such a broad question that can not be answered here.